# Combining lists of objects containing lists of objects in c#

Tags: c#, list, foreach

The title is a little prosaic, I know. I have 3 classes (Users, Cases, Offices). Users and Cases contain a list of Offices inside of them. I need to compare the Office lists from Users and Cases and if the ID's of Offices match, I need to add those IDs from Cases to the Users. So the end goal is to have the Users class have any Offices that match the Offices in the Cases class.

To add clarity, I am looking to compare the two officeLists (users.officeList and cases.OfficeList) and when any Cases.OfficeList.ID == Users.OfficeList.ID, I need to add that Case.ID to the list of Users.caseAdminIDList

Any ideas?

My code (which isnt working)

```
         foreach (Users users in userList)
            foreach (Cases cases in caseList)
                foreach (Offices userOffice in users.officeList)
                    foreach (Offices caseOffice in cases.officeList)
                    {
                        if (userOffice.ID == caseOffice.ID)
                            users.caseAdminIDList.Add(cases.adminID);
                    }//end foreach
```

//start my data classes

```
class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        List<Offices> officeList = new List<Offices>();
        List<int> caseAdminIDList = new List<int>();
        ID = 0;
    }//end constructor

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int adminID { get; set; }
    public string ADuserName { get; set; }
    public bool alreadyInDB { get; set; }
    public bool alreadyInAdminDB { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
    public List<int> caseAdminIDList { get; set; }
    public List<Offices> officeList { get; set; }

}

class Offices
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}


class Cases
{
    public Cases()
    {
        List<Offices> officeList = new List<Offices>();
        ID = 0;
    }//end constructor

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int adminID { get; set; }
    public bool alreadyInDB { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
    public List<Offices> officeList { get; set; }

}
```

//in my main method

```
           private bool grabCasesFromAdminDB() //gets cases from DB1 (AdminDB)
    {
        DatabaseIO dbIO = new DatabaseIO();
        caseList = dbIO.getCasesFromAdminDB(adminDBConString, caseList).ToList();
        if (dbIO.errorMessage == null || dbIO.errorMessage.Equals(""))
        {
            if (getCaseOfficeRelationship())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }//end if
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dbIO.errorMessage, "Admin DB Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }//end else
    }//end method


    private bool grabCasesFromListDB()//grabs cases from the main db
    {
        DatabaseIO dbIO = new DatabaseIO();
        caseList = dbIO.getCasesFromMainDB(connectionString, caseList).ToList();
        if (dbIO.errorMessage == null || dbIO.errorMessage.Equals(""))
            return true;
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dbIO.errorMessage, "Main DB Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }//end else

    }//end method


    private bool getCaseOfficeRelationship()//adds office relationship to cases
    {
        DatabaseIO dbIO = new DatabaseIO();
        caseList = dbIO.getOfficeToCaseRelationship(connectionString, caseList).ToList();
        if (dbIO.errorMessage == null || dbIO.errorMessage.Equals(""))
        {
            if (getOfficeNamesByID())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }//end if
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dbIO.errorMessage, "Cases To Offices Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }//end else
    }//end method


    private bool getOfficeNamesByID()//grabs the id of the offices by name
    {
        List<Offices> officeList = new List<Offices>();
        DatabaseIO dbIO = new DatabaseIO();
        officeList = dbIO.getOfficeNamesByOfficeID(connectionString).ToList();
        if (dbIO.errorMessage == null || dbIO.errorMessage.Equals(""))
        {
            matchOfficeNamesToIDs(officeList);
            return true;
        }//end if
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dbIO.errorMessage, "Getting Office List Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }//end else
    }//end method


    private void matchOfficeNamesToIDs(List<Offices> officeList)
    {
        foreach (Cases cases in caseList)
            if (cases.officeList != null)
                foreach (Offices office in cases.officeList)
                {
                    foreach (Offices innerOffice in officeList)
                        if (innerOffice.ID == office.ID)
                            office.name = innerOffice.name;
                }//end foreach
    }//end method
```

//an example of my DBIO class

```
        public List<Cases> getCasesFromAdminDB(string adminDBConString, List<Cases> caseList)
    {
        try
        {
            Cases cases = null;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = adminDBConString;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            command.CommandText = "select CS_Case_ID, Case_Name from CS_Case where CS_Product_Type_ID = 2 and CS_Case_Status_ID = 1";
            SqlDataReader thisReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            int idxID = thisReader.GetOrdinal("CS_Case_ID");
            int idxName = thisReader.GetOrdinal("Case_Name");
            while (thisReader.Read())
            {
                bool found = false;
                foreach (Cases tempCase in caseList)
                {
                    if (tempCase.adminID == Int32.Parse(thisReader.GetValue(idxID).ToString()))
                    {
                        tempCase.alreadyInDB = true;
                        found = true;
                    }//end if
                }//end foreach
                if (!found)
                {
                    cases = new Cases();
                    cases.adminID = Int32.Parse(thisReader.GetValue(idxID).ToString());
                    cases.name = thisReader.GetValue(idxName).ToString();
                    cases.alreadyInDB = false;
                    cases.officeList = new List<Offices>();
                    caseList.Add(cases);
                }//end if
            }//end while
            thisReader.Close();
            return caseList;
        }//end try
        catch (Exception excep1)
        {
            errorMessage = "Cases could not be loaded from the Admin Console." + "\r\n" + "Error message: " + excep1.ToString();
            return caseList;
        }//end catch

    }//end method
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated!

Comment: How isn't it working?  What do you expect the results to be?  What results are you actually getting?  How are you setting those variables before those `foreach` loops?

Comment: So to be clear, each `User` has multiple offices, and each `Case` has multiple offices, and in each `User` you want to store the `adminID` of any `Case` which has at least one office in common with that `User`?

Comment: I just added some additional info for clarity

Answer (score 2):

Complex querying like this is best handled by LINQ. If you had a common element on both `Users` and `Cases`, then this would be a job for a `join`. But in this case instead of a common element, they each contain lists, and you want to "join" on those where the two lists have a common element.

So, to start off, what's the condition for a particular case to be included for a user?

```
case.officeList.Any(caseOffice => user.officeList.Any(userOffice => caseOffice.ID == userOffice.ID))
```

i.e. Any office in the case's officeList is contained in the user's `officeList`.

Now we have that condition, we can use it in a LINQ `Where` clause to pull out all the desired case:

```
caseList.Where(case =>
    case.officeList.Any(caseOffice => user.officeList.Any(userOffice => caseOffice.ID == userOffice.ID)))
```

That returns our collection of cases, so finally we just want to `Select` out the part of the case we need, the adminID.

```
caseList.Where(case =>
    case.officeList.Any(caseOffice => user.officeList.Any(userOffice => caseOffice.ID == userOffice.ID)))
     .Select(case => case.adminID);
```

So putting that all together:

```
foreach(Users users in userList)
{
    users.caseAdminIDList = caseList.Where(case =>
    case.officeList.Any(caseOffice => user.officeList.Any(userOffice => caseOffice.ID == userOffice.ID)))
     .Select(case => case.adminID).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I think you left out an inner foreach on the last code block, but yes this is the way to do it.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. I misunderstood the original code.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote, whoever that was?

Comment: No idea why downvotes are being cast when we don't even know the error with the OP's code. My guess is my answer is tackling the "null reference error" the OP might have, but yours and Ben's answer are "possible improvements". Again, not voting, just observing.

Comment: It could be that this doesn't address the user's actual question rather than improve upon it. The actual problem was solved with gunr's post, but this still stands as a great improvement to the original code. +1 since this was way better than mine...

Comment: We don't even know what the OP's problem is. Given that we don't even know what's wrong, the answer clearly doesn't provide an answer to that problem.  If/when the question is improved to actually become answerable, then the answers can be judged on whether or not they solve the problem.

Comment: Well, time to use that new close option.

Comment: @DanH Well you should still update your original question to clarify it for any future readers. Then maybe you'll get some upvotes :)

Comment: I spoke too soon. This never returns any results, regardless of whether there are matches or not. I added more info to the original post for clarity.

Comment: @DanH So what's the exact result? An exception is thrown? No exception is thrown but `users.caseAdminIDList` remains empty?

Comment: The list remains empty

Comment: @DanH Are you getting the data from some real source, or have you put together a small example just for testing? If the former, could you try the latter, test if it's still not working, and if not, include the test code in your question?

Comment: I am grabbing the data from a database (but it is all test data). If I print out the data, many users and cases have the same offices associated among themselves. I added some of the code from Main and my DatabaseIO classes

Comment: @DanH Try the updated version. It's possible that the equality comparison being used for the `Contains` method wasn't appropriate

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an error on the bottom select (.Select(cases => cases.adminID)). The error is: bool does not contain a definition for select and no extension method Select accepting a first argument type bool could be found

Comment: @DanH Try updated version

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I still get no results. Here are a few pics of the GUI: http://s27.postimg.org/6idn4l0w3/cases.png    http://s29.postimg.org/uec6ikdvb/users.png   You can see there are offices associated to both

Comment: I just echo printed and the office ids are indeed inside of the correct objects, so the data is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cases()
{
    List<Offices> officeList = new List<Offices>();
    ID = 0;
}//end constructor
```

This is making a new varaible called `officeList`. It will not use the `officeList` outside the constructor.

This needs to be changed to:

```
officeList = new List<Offices>();
```

This will properly initialize the class field.

Comment: I have also tried this and it was unable to resolve my issue. Thank you for your time though!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your Offices class like this:

```
    class Offices:IEquatable<Offices>
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }



        public bool Equals(Offices other)
        {
            return this.ID.Equals(other.ID);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.ID.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then in your code to have the Users class have any Offices that match the Offices in the Cases class just do this;

```
usersVariable.CaseAdminIDList = usersVariable.OfficeList.Intersect(casesVariable.OfficeList).Select(o => o.ID).ToList();
```

Also in your users and cases class you need to initialize the list properly(you are using automatic properties and in ctor declaring and initializing a whole new variable),something
like this for example:

```
    class Users
    {
        public Users()
        {
            officeList = new List<Offices>();
            caseAdminIDList = new List<int>();
            ID = 0;
        }//end constructor

        private List<Offices> officeList;
        public List<Offices> OfficeList
        {
            get { return officeList; }
            set { officeList = value; }
        }

        private List<int> caseAdminIDList;
        public List<int> CaseAdminIDList 
        {
            get { return caseAdminIDList; }
            set { caseAdminIDList = value; }
        }

        //other members.....
     }
```